# any difference between randomly selecting before or after an event?

Tags: experiment-design, random-allocation

Is there a mathematical difference between randomly selecting a population of users before an event vs after an event, for the purposes of experimentation?

For example, let's say we want to split all users that perform event X into two groups, A and B.  A is 90% of the users (randomly selected) and B is 10% of the users.

Is there any difference if we first randomly split all users into two groups, A and B, at 90% and 10% respectively, and then of all those users, those who perform event X, they will then be sorted based on their already-membership in group A or B?

Comment: Your example is unclear. You have `event A` and `group A`. So when you say `A is 90% of the users`, which `A` is being referred to. Btw, why would you use the same letter to describe two separate entities in an example?

Comment: sorry about that, I didn't proofread.  I initially wrote 90%/10% but then thought to simplify it with A and B, but then forgot I used A for the event name.

Comment: The descriptions of "sorting" and "splitting" are obscure in this question.  Could you provide a small example to show what it is you are contemplating?

Comment: @whuber, sorry that's my fault.  I meant sorting and splitting to mean the same thing but I wasn't sure exactly how it should be worded.  In the above example, what I meant to say was: once a user performs event X, then afterwards, all the participants would then be put into the same A and B buckets that they were selected in before the event X.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will answer with a cautious **No**.

Imagine that I select 100 volunteers to play a carnival game. They must make a basketball shot. That is our `event X`. Let's say we know that the average person makes the shot 60% of the time.

**Scenario 1 - Divide first then shoot**

90 of the volunteers go to group A and 10 are assigned to group B. 60% of the volunteers make the shot as expected. Leaving us with 54 (90*0.6) in A and 6 (10*0.6) in B.

**Scenario 2 - Shoot first then divide**

All 100 volunteers shoot the basket and 60% make the shot as expected. Group A will have 54 and B will have 6.

**Conclusion**

No difference. The same probability distribution results. A smarter person will be able to prove this mathematically. But the crucial bit is that membership to a group must, in itself, not alter the probability of `event X` occurring.

Comment: Thank you.  So if there is any bias in terms of how event X were achieved, for example, basketball players would be naturally selected for, then that would alter the results and the grouping would be different?

Comment: Yes. If there is something different about the groups that will affect the outcome then you group prior to the event.

Comment: The two are *slightly* different in the possibly irrelevant sense that in Scenario 2, *exactly* 90 percent will be assigned Group A by construction while in Scenario 1, *on average* 90 percent will be assigned Group A. But the two are basically the same in the sense that if assignment to Group A is random, it will be independent of event $X$ and all other predetermined unobservables in either scenario (unless of course event $X$ is somehow a function of assignment to group A).

Comment: As Pierre mentioned, "the crucial bit is that membership to a group must, in itself, not alter the probability of event X occurring." For example, if Group A eats a big tub of ice cream, they may get a belly ache and miss free throws at a higher rate (i.e. event X is less likely to occur if assignment to Group A occurs first).